# HTTPS redirection leading to a 404 error page

Tags: nginx

I have the following server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 308 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

however when accessing the url `http://localhost/coletor` a 404 error appears and while accessing through https the url loads correctly. What am I doing wrong?

access.log:

```
2022/09/01 17:04:27 [error] 26#26: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/coletor" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.27.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /coletor HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
172.27.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2022:17:04:27 +0000] "GET /coletor HTTP/1.1" 404 187 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

My entire nginx.conf:

```
user 'www-data';
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    ssl_session_cache            shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout          10m;
    sendfile                     on;
    tcp_nopush                   on;
    tcp_nodelay                  on;

    keepalive_timeout            3600;
    proxy_read_timeout           3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout        3600;
    proxy_send_timeout           3600;
    send_timeout                 3600;
    client_body_timeout          3600;
    lingering_timeout            3600;
    resolver_timeout             3600;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout      3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout         3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout         3600;

    types_hash_max_size          2048;
    include                      /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                 application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols                TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers    on;
    ssl_ciphers                  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    access_log                   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log                    /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    gzip                         on;
    gzip_disable                 "msie6";
    include                      /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    client_max_body_size         200M;
    
    map $cookie_version $version_cookie_host {
        include /etc/nginx/versions/*.conf;
    }

    map $http_app_version $version_header_host {
        include /etc/nginx/versions/*.conf;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 308 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/nexello.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/nexello.key;
        server_name             _;

        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip  $remote_addr;
        set $auth_host 172.17.0.1;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            if ($request_uri ~ .*coletor.*) {
                proxy_pass https://$version_cookie_host;
            }

            if ($cookie_token) {
                proxy_pass https://$version_cookie_host;
            }

            if ($http_authorization) {
                proxy_pass https://$version_header_host;
            }

            if ($request_uri ~ .*/auth/.*) {
                proxy_pass https://$auth_host:7001;
            }

            proxy_pass https://$auth_host:7001;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files. Look for another `server` block containing `server_name localhost;`

Comment: @RichardSmith God damnit, you were right, there was an extra file at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Could you put what you said as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message contains `server: localhost` - which is referring to the value of `server_name` in the `server` block causing the error.

The `server` blocks in your question all contain `server_name _;` - so there must be another `server` block hidden in an included file.

Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files.